# graphene-django returns wrong filtered data

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django, django-filters

I have a DjangoObjectType and a Filterset class for my query. I have added a filter for my DjangoObjectType class as below.

```
class MyFilter(FilterSet):
    quantity = NumberFilter(method='filter_quantity')

    def filter_quantity(self, queryset, name, value):
        a_data = ClassA.objects.filter(quantity__gte=value)
        a_data_keys = [data.key_number for data in a_data]
        return queryset.filter(key__in=a_data_keys)
```

When I run my query without any filter, it works correctly and returns all the data. However, when I run it e.g with the `quantity: 1` filter, it returns data with just `quantity: 1`, same as for 2. It doesn't return `equal or greater`. I have some data with `quantity: 3`. When I run the query with this filter and 3, it returns just `quantity: 4`. I'm really confused what's wrong with this. When I print the query filter result before return, it seems correct. But in the graphql query result dict, it's wrong. Do you have any idea about how can I fix this weird issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because this is a limited snippet of the code involved, and this doesn't look wrong. Could it be possible that this filter is not being applied by graphene? are you using a `DjangoFilterConnection` field? Maybe you need a resolve method as follows?

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    filtered_stuff = DjangoFilterConnectionField(StuffType)

    def resolve_filtered_stuff(self, info, **filters):
        return MyFilter(filters).qs
```